# Text To speech in openCv using C++

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

actually this is the first time to post a question on stcakoverflow. I have a question about opencv. right now I am working to develop a program takes an attendance using face detection and face recognition where the student stands front of the webcam to detect and recognize his face, this is not a problem. the feature which I want to add is when the program recognizes the student's face, I want the program to pronounces his name. Is there any algorithm to do that using OpenCv. Please anyone has experience or knowledge about that help me.

Thank you for all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is a computer vision library and it has nothing to do with text-to-speech. You need an appropriate speech synthesis engine, like [Flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/index.html) or [Festival](http://festvox.org/festival/).

Comment: So there isn't any method to pronounce the name when the face recognized.

Comment: Not in OpenCV. You need a text-to-speech library.